# Loading custom notation on startup without showing the Notation palette

Tags: packages

I was creating some custom notations using the Notation package and it works fine.
I put it in my default personal package, and it loads fine on *Mathematica*'s startup.
To make it complete I need just one more thing.
How can I suppress the Notation palette from appearing every time I launch *Mathematica*?
Is there some command that I can put into my package?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [answer](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/tutorial/OptionsAndAuxiliaryFunctions.html#979137619) is to set

```
Notation`AutoLoadNotationPalette = False
```

prior to loading `` Notation` ``, e.g.

```
Notation`AutoLoadNotationPalette = False
(* .... *)
Needs["Notation`"]
```

or

```
Notation`AutoLoadNotationPalette = False
(* .... *)
BeginPackage["MyPackage`", {"Notation`"}]
```

Comment: Exact what I need! Tks!

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using `Block`:

```
Block[{Notation`AutoLoadNotationPalette = False},
  Needs["Notation`"]
]
```

Or:

```
Block[{Notation`AutoLoadNotationPalette = False},
  BeginPackage["MyPackage`", {"Notation`"}]
]
```

This way you do not prevent the palette from displaying when the user calls `` << Notation` ``, which could be aggravating.

Comment: Now I understand how it works!.. Nice block application. tks

Comment: @Murta I love those moments of recognition. :-)

Comment: You deserve, sorry for the delay! %)

Comment: @Murta I think perhaps my prior comment was misunderstood.  I was referring to moments of suddenly understanding something, which I find a pleasant sensation.  I did not mean that I was seeking personal recognition, though I admit that too can be nice.

Comment: Wow!.. yes.. I really misunderstood. But no problems because you still deserves .. rsrs. Now, about the intelectual  recognition moment, yes! it's amazing.